# Can moving tables to another MySQL database help performance?

Tags: mysql, performance, performance-tuning

I want to know if I using different databases can help performance.

I have one big table *support_chat* with more than 5 million rows. I need to scan this all the time (3s with ajax) to check new messages on support.

If I move this table to another database in the same computer, can it help anything? (let users, sells, comments table faster)

For example:

#### db1

```
users table
sells table
comments table
support_chat table // move this table to db2
```

#### db2

```
support_chat table
```

They want to keep old things due legal reasons, to have a user support history.

Comment: That is highly unlikely to help. You are better off making sure you have good indexes and are only querying relevant data/rows (Ex: I am guessing you don't need to poll support_chat entries from a year ago.).

Comment: I would guess you're not doing anything that wasteful, but without examples of the queries you're dealing with, that is pretty much the only advice that can be given. (If you can't change code/queries, you could perhaps look into table partitioning.)

Comment: You need to add more detail to your question, such as:  What indexes are in place?  Is the machine running your MySQL database running other software as well?  How much RAM is in the server? etc., etc.

Comment: You should check the query doing the scan if it can be optimized. 5 million rows is not a big number so it should be fast to get new messages, but you have to define the "new" right and use proper indexing.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, no. A few tangentially related things to note though:

1. You could use a symlink to move the `/<datadir>/db2/` directory to another storage/block device. Or you could use the `CREATE TABLE ... DATADIR=/../` option to move only the support_chat table to another storage/block device. That could make a big difference, assuming that you're frequently disk bound.
2. With MySQL 5.6, using multiple databases/schemas can help to improve slave throughput (assuming you're using replication) because the parallelization was at the schema level:

   [Replication Slave Options and Variables `--slave-parallel-workers`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_slave-parallel-workers)

   So with three databases/schemas, you would benefit from setting `slave-parallel-workers=3`.

For more info on the multi-threaded slave work in MySQL 5.6:

[MySQL Replication High Performance: Multi-Threaded Slaves and
Group Commit](http://www.mysql.com/news-and-events/events/innovation-day/slides/MySQL_Innovation_Day_Replication_High_Performance.pdf) (pdf)

Just FYI, the multi-threaded slave behavior has been greatly improved in MySQL 5.7 too, the biggest example being that you can now instead use (Lamport) logical clock based parallelization:

[Replication Slave Options and Variables `--slave-parallel-type`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_slave-parallel-type)

Answer (score 2):

Just to answer your question, no, it won't. MySQL runs your queries in parallel anyway so a single instance with multiple threads is not fundamentally different from multiple MySQL processes on the same host.

I see two probable causes here:

- You haven't set up proper indexes to match the pattern of access for `support_chat`.
- You're storing too much variable data in `support_chat`'s rows, e.g. you're storing whole transcripts, attachments, etc. In that case choosing a more suitable schema for your use case would help (for instance, if you're storing chat messages on `support_chat` as they arrive then you should consider having a separate `chat_message` table).